# Category of preordered sets is not balanced

Tags: category-theory

As the question states, I have to show that the category **Ord** is not balanced.

Doing so involves constructing a morphism $f$ which is monic and epic but is not an isomorphism. In **Ord**, the functions which are monic and epic are exactly the functions which are both injective and surjective. So consider $A = \{ a, b \}$ with $a \leq b$ and $b \leq a$ and $B = \{ a, b \}$ with $a \leq b$. Now consider the monic and epic morphism $f : A \to B$ defined by $f(a_A) = a_B$ and $f(b_A) = b_B$. I claim that there is no inverse to $f$ which preserves the ordering. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you probably wanted to go the other way around, otherwise the $f$ is not preorder preserving: you have $b_A \leq a_A$ but 
$$f(b_A)=b_B \not\leq a_B=f(a_A)\ .$$

Nevertheless is you reverse the roles of $A$ and $B$ meaning that you let
$$\begin{align*}
f \colon B &\longrightarrow A\\
f(b_B) &= b_A \\
f(a_B) &= a_A
\end{align*}$$
the you actually get bijective preorder-preserving map, that does not have an inverse preorder preserving (I assume that the details are obvious to complete).

Comment: Ahh you are right. I meant to say that $a \leq b$ in A, and $a \leq b$, $b \leq a$ in B.

Comment: That's why I said _I suppose that_ :-D